# Bootstrap Popover + Angular: Keep the popover open when hoovering over the popover box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I have a problem that is driving me crazy for days. I need to show a popover with links when hoovering a button. The popover must be open when the mouse is hoovering the button or the popover box.

What I need is an Angular version of this example I found on Plunker:

```js
// Code goes here

    
$(".pop").popover({ trigger: "manual" , html: true, animation:false})
    .on("mouseenter", function () {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");
            }
        }, 300);
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.box {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#DDD;
}
#pop {
    padding:0px 0px;
}
#example {
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  
</head>

<body>
  <h2 class='text-primary'>Another Great "KISS" Bootstrap Popover example!</h2>
  <p class='text-muted'>KISS = Keep It Simple S....</p>
  
  <p class='text-primary'>Goal:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Open popover on hover event for the popover button</li>
<li>Keep popover open when hovering over the popover box</li>
<li>Close popover on mouseleave for either the popover button, or the popover box.</li>
  </ul>
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pop" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Optional parameter: Skip if this was not requested<br>                                    A placement group is a logical grouping of instances within a single Availability                                     Zone. Using placement groups enables applications to get the full-bisection bandwidth                                     and low-latency network performance required for tightly coupled, node-to-node                                     communication typical of HPC applications.<br>                                    This only applies to cluster compute instances: cc2.8xlarge, cg1.4xlarge, cr1.8xlarge, hi1.4xlarge and hs1.8xlarge.<br>                                    More info: <a href=&quot;http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;>Click here...</a>"
  data-original-title="" title="">
    HOVER OVER ME
    </button>
    <br><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pop" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Optional parameter: Skip if this was not requested<br>                                    A placement group is a logical grouping of instances within a single Availability                                     Zone. Using placement groups enables applications to get the full-bisection bandwidth                                     and low-latency network performance required for tightly coupled, node-to-node                                     communication typical of HPC applications.<br>                                    This only applies to cluster compute instances: cc2.8xlarge, cg1.4xlarge, cr1.8xlarge, hi1.4xlarge and hs1.8xlarge.<br>                                    More info: <a href=&quot;http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;>Click here...</a>"
  data-original-title="" title="">
    HOVER OVER ME... Again!
    </button><br><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pop" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Optional parameter: Skip if this was not requested<br>                                    A placement group is a logical grouping of instances within a single Availability                                     Zone. Using placement groups enables applications to get the full-bisection bandwidth                                     and low-latency network performance required for tightly coupled, node-to-node                                     communication typical of HPC applications.<br>                                    This only applies to cluster compute instances: cc2.8xlarge, cg1.4xlarge, cr1.8xlarge, hi1.4xlarge and hs1.8xlarge.<br>                                    More info: <a href=&quot;http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;>Click here...</a>"
  data-original-title="" title="">
    Okay one more time... !
    </button>
  <br><br>
  <p class='text-info'>Hope that helps you... Drove me crazy for a while</p>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Unfortunately I am new to Angular and have no idea how to translate this jquery example to Angular.

Comment: have you try to do it angular?

Comment: Use UIBootstrap or AngularStrap.

Comment: @Paresh Gami: I did try, but I am new to Angular and have no idela how to attach to popover box mouse events.

Comment: @The Head Rush: They don't give any extra option to control the popover box on hoover

Answer (score 0):

Angular UI has UI Bootstrap, which offers a lot of commonly used JQuery and Bootstrap plugins in angular.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover

There is UI Bootstrap Popover, and you can configure to respond to mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Comment: UI Bootstrap Popover does not give any mouse events for popover box. Only target element events can be configured.